# Dynamic Loading of AngularJS controllers/views using SystemJS

Tags: angularjs, systemjs

Is there a way to structure/write AngularJS in a modular way that ***dynamically 
loads/require*** `controllers/views` depending on page routes in SystemJS  ?

**EDIT:** 
This is what I currently have, as a trial to use SystemJS

**app.js** - This is the main file that gets import in *index.html*

```
// vendor
import angular from 'angular';

//Controllers
import controllers from './controllers/_index.js'

// Routes
import routes from './routes/routes.config.js';

var seedApp = angular.module('seedApp', ['seedApp.route', 'seedApp.controllers']);


angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    return angular.bootstrap(document.body, [seedApp.name], {
        strictDi: true
    });
});

export default seedApp;
```

***_index.js*** - Index for all controllers

```
import { navCtrl } from './nav.js';
import { aboutCtrl } from './about.js';

var app = angular.module('seedApp.controllers', []);

app.controller('navCtrl', navCtrl);
app.controller('aboutCtrl', aboutCtrl);
```

***routes.config.js***

```
import 'angular-ui-router';

var app = angular.module('seedApp.route', ['ui.router']);


app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutCtrl as about'
        });
}]);

export default app;
```

Comment: Yes there would be. What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited the question with some additional information. I assumed that the using Babel's system module would automatically make everything dynamic via system.register. 

However on second thought, since I am loading all angular modules at once, it might not work. Hence this question arise.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer `NO`.
Long answer `YES`, but you need to use [ocLayzLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) angular plugin because this is not natively supported by Angular 1.x ( this will be possible in Angular 2.x ). 
Btw, if you are trying to dynamically load file, you need to use `System.import`

Hope that's helped.